# CPanel Cron Job automaticically changes my setting/configuration

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I'm setting up a cron job via cpanel, i'm setting it up that it will run a script every minute, during a couple of hours like 24-35 hours, it works well but after that one, it seems like my Cron job isn't working anymore.

When I checked back the configuration of cron job in cpanel, I noticed that it changed, 
From : 
`* * * * *` it went to `*/19 * * * *`

I switched it back again to `* * * * *` , but a couple of hours again, it switches back to `*/19 * * * *` or something random.

Why is this happening? Is this a server issue, like my server doesn't allow me to run the script every minute because maybe it over loads? or should I forget setting up a cron job via cpanel and do it via PHP?

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted my hosting provider and told me that it won't allow me to set a cron job every minute because i'm just using a shared hosting. So we just bought a Dedicated hosting then set up my cron job to run every minute, then it worked flawlessly.

Thanks! :)